# Reverse mapping in KVM

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, linux-kernel, kvm

I am in pursuit of a mechanism to obtain a Guest Virtual Address (gVA) given a Guest Physical Address (gPA) in KVM. I am completely new to this  area with very limited knowledge of KVM/linux memory management, so please bear with me while I try to elaborate on the problem statement.

Since linux-2.6, a mechanism called Object-based Reverse Mapping (objrmap) is being used to invalidate the all the PTEs referencing to a page frame before swapping the page out from memory. I understand the anon_vma data structure cleverly collects all memory region descriptors relative to a given page frame -  and one basically uses the fact that these memory region descriptors have a pointer to the page table containing all PTEs referencing the page frame, to invalidate them. In a native setting (no virtualization), one could easily use the anon_vma data structure to find a virtual address for a given page frame within the process linear address space by doing some simple arithmetic: Combine the vm_start from the region descriptor (vm_area_struct) and the page->index from the page descriptor (struct page).

`VA = anon_vma->vma_area_struct->vm_start + page->index`

**Here is an image from Understanding the Linux Kernel, Edition 3 describing this mechanism for anonymous pages**

[image]

I was hoping to do something similar to find the gVA given a gPA within KVM assuming Two-Dimensional Paging (TDP) is enabled. However, as I skimmed through the KVM code, I see that KVM implements a reverse mapping scheme wherein in stores a pointer to all the PTEs that refer to a GFN (Guest Frame Number), as opposed to implementing objrmap. Since it needs to support 3 different page sizes on x86 (4kB, 2MB, 1GB), it stores pointers to L1, L2 and L3 guest PTEs. As I cannot obtain the memory region descriptor, I cannot use the aforementioned mechanism wherein I combine vm_start and page_index.

I have the following questions.

- If only I had access to the L4 guest PTE, I was planning to do the following arithmetic to determine the guest virtual address:

`gVA[47:39] = (Address of L4 PTE  - guest CR3)/PTE size`

`gVA[38:30] = (Address of L3 PTE - L4 PTE PFN)/PTE size`

`gVA[29:21] = (Address of L2 PTE -  L3 PTE PFN)/PTE size`

`gVA[20:12] = (Address of L1 PTE - L2 PTE PFN)/PTE size`

Is this approach correct? If so, is there any way to obtain the L4 guest PTE?

- Is there any other easy approach to do this which involve exploiting fields in kvm_mmu_page? I can't seem to think of any.

Can the experts please comment? I appreciate any help that may come my way. Thanks.